# Add iferror() for every error that occurs in sheet but keeps formula in this cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet with a lot of formulas. some of them gives me an error. I'd like to make something similar to ctrl+h and replace values but I'd love to find every cell that is giving an error and replace it with *iferror(formula that exists in the cell;"bd")*

Do you know if there is any fast solution so I don't have to do it manually for most of the formulas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a clean printable copy of the sheet, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

`=arrayformula(iferror(Sheet1!A1:Z))`

To add the `iferror()` directly in the formulas in the original sheet, choose **Edit > Find and replace** and use something like this:

- **Find:** `^=(.+)$`
- **Replace with:** `=iferror($1)`
- **Search:** `this sheet`
- ☑️  **Search using regular expressions**
- ☑️  **Also search within formulas**
- **Replace all**